# Why i can't edit my previous data added in the table only the new data added gets edited?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

so i'm creating a table with add feature in my add users its already adding but when i press the edit or update in that row its editable and can also be saved but when i add new user on that table the previous table can't be edited and same goes through only the new user is getting edited this is the example image

[image: This is my first user it can be edited]

[image: Now i want to edit my previous data which is tian it only editing the new add]

**-> This is my function for adding user**

```
const handleAddUser = () => {
  if (editUser) {
    updateUser(selectedUser.id, name, emailAddress, role);
    setEditUser(false);
  } else {
    addUser(name, emailAddress, role);
  }
  setName("");
  setEmailAddress("");
  setRole("");
  handleCloseUser();
};
```

**-> This is my function for editing user**

```
const handleEditUser = (index) => {
  const selectedUser = users[index];
  setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
  setName(selectedUser.name);
  setEmailAddress(selectedUser.emailAddress);
  setRole(selectedUser.role);
  setEditUser(true);
  handleOpenUser();
};
```

**-> This is my zustand code**

```
 editUser: false,
 setEditUser: (newEditUser) => set({editUser: newEditUser}), 

 /* Storing of Users  */
 addUser: (name, emailAddress, role) =>
 set((store) => ({ 
  users: [
    ...store.users, 
    { id: uuidv4(), name, emailAddress, role },
  ],
 })),
 updateUser: (userId, name, emailAddress, role) => 
 set((store) => ({
  users: store.users.map((user) => 
    user.id === userId
    ? { ...user, name, emailAddress, role }
    : user
  ),
  })),
```

**-> This is my table looks like**

```
<MUI.TableBody>
  {users
    .filter((user) => filteredRole === "All" || user.role === filteredRole)
    .map(
      (user, index) =>
        (user.name || user.emailAddress || user.role) && (
          <MUI.TableRow key={index} className="user">
            <MUI.TableCell sx={{ border: "none" }} className="name">
              {user.name}
            </MUI.TableCell>
            <MUI.TableCell sx={{ border: "none" }} className="email">
              {user.emailAddress}
            </MUI.TableCell>
            <MUI.TableCell sx={{ border: "none" }} className="role">
              {user.role}
            </MUI.TableCell>
            <MUI.TableCell sx={{ border: "none" }}>
              <MUI.IconButton
                color="inherit"
                onClick={handleClick}
                sx={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
              >
                <MUI.MoreHorizIcon />
              </MUI.IconButton>

              <MUI.Menu
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={handleClose}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "bottom",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
              >
                <MUI.MenuItem onClick={() => handleEditUser(index)}>
                  Update
                </MUI.MenuItem>

                <MUI.MenuItem
                  onClick={() => {
                    deleteRow(users.length - 1);
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </MUI.MenuItem>
              </MUI.Menu>
            </MUI.TableCell>
          </MUI.TableRow>
        )
    )}
</MUI.TableBody>;
```

Comment: Please share this code on codesandbox, So we can look into the issue in more detail.